# How can I step through my Android Studio Application, line-by-line?

Tags: java, android

I want to see, line by line, only the Java and XML code that I have written.

I'd like it to start, display one line of code at a time, pause, and continue to display, line by line, my entire running application.

I don't know if it is possible to view both the Java and XML code as it is being processed.

I have tried going to File, Settings, Debugger, Stepping, and then selecting different choices on the right, but I guess the choices I made were incorrect, because it is not displaying my lines of Java and XML code.

Comment: Set a break-point and step through it? Your IDE should provide debugging tools for this.

Comment: Yes you can step over by pressing F8 when a break point is hit in the AndroidStudio

Comment: You cannot view the XML code as it is being processed, only the Java code. Android layout XML is parsed, not executed, so it is not possible to step through it.

Answer (score 3):

Basic steps:

1. Set breakpoints on your code
   In Android Studio, this is done by clicking on the gutter (the space beside  the line numbers)
2. Go to Run -> Debug 'app'
3. Wait for the debugger..
4. The **Debugger** tab will be displayed. You can then use the controls (step over, step into, etc.) to go through your code line by line.

There's more info from the nice documentation on using the debugger from the Android docs:
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

> I have tried going to File, Settings, Debugger, Stepping

This just configures the IDE's debugger settings.
It doesn't actually run it.